# Looking for the perfect morse

Tags: morse-theory

A Morse function $f(x)\colon \mathbb{R}^n\to \mathbb{R}$ is a smooth function s.t. all singular points are non-degenerate. A theorem of Sard implies that for any smooth $f(x)$ and almost all $a\in \mathbb{R}^n$ the function $f(x) + ax$ is Morse.

A Morse function $f$ is called perfect Morse if in addition the singular values are distinct.

Question: Is there an analog for perfect Morse, i.e., given smooth $f(x)$ is $f(x) + ax$ perfect Morse for almost all $a$?

Comment: Perfect Morse function usually means something else (that the differential in the Morse chain complex vanishes).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The answer to your question is negative. A counterexample is given by the Morse function

$f:\mathbb{R}\to \mathbb{R}, \;\; f(x)=\sin(x). $

Using this example it is easy to produce higher dimensional counterexamples.

(The Morse functions with at most one critical point per level set were called *excellent* by R. Thom. They are also known as *stable functions*.  They form an open and dense subset in the space of smooth functions on a manifold.)

**Re-Edit**  (*Following Mark Grant's  observation.*) If $f:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ is a polynomial

$$f(x)=x^n+\sum_{j=0}^{n-1} a_j x^j, $$

then your  guess is correct.   Namely for all but finitely many $a$'s  the function $f_a(x):=f(x)-ax$ is excellent.   Here is the argument.

Consider the real algebraic set $\newcommand{\bR}{\mathbb{R}}$

$$ Z=\lbrace (x,a) \in\bR^2;\;\; f'(x)=a\rbrace. $$

We have a natural projection  $\alpha: Z\to \bR$, $(x,a)\mapsto a$, whose fibers are finite sets. This is a semialgebraic map so that there exist finitely many  real numbers

$$A_0< A_1< ... < A_N$$

such that  the map $\alpha$ is a $C^3$-covering map over each of the intervals $(-\infty, A_0)$, $(A_0,A_1)$, ... $(A_N,\infty)$.

Let $I$ be one of these intervals. The set

$$ Z(I):=\lbrace (x,a)\in Z;\;\;a\in I\rbrace $$

consists of  the graphs of finitely many twice differentiable semialgebraic functions

$$ u_1,...,u_m: I\to\mathbb{R} $$

such that $ u_i(a) < u_{i+1}(a)$, $\forall a, i$. In other words, the  set of critical points of $f_a$, $a\in I$ is $u_1(a),\dotsc , u_m(a)$.

I claim that for all but finitely many $a$'s in $I$ the function $f_a$ is excellent. I argue by contradiction.  If this were not the case,  then the semialgebraicity of the $u_i$'s implies that there exist an open interval $ J\subset I$  and  pair of indices $(i,j)$,  $i\neq j$,  such that

$$ f_a( u_i(a) )= f_a( u_j(a) ), \;\;f'(u_i(a))=f'(u_j(a))=a,\;\;\forall a\in J.$$

The first equality can be rewritten as

$$ f(u_i)- f(u_j)= a(u_i-u_j). $$

Differentiating the above equality with respect to $a$ and recalling that $f'(u_i)=f'(u_j)=a$ we deduce

$$ a(u_i'-u_j')= (u_i-u_j)+ a(u_i'-u_j'). $$

This clearly implies

$$ u_i(a)=u_j(a),\;\;\forall a\in J. $$

*Contradiction!*

**Note.** The same is true for any polynomial $f$ in any number of variables. The [proof in the general case](http://liviusmathblog.blogspot.com/2012/07/excellent-polynomial-mappings.html)  is very similar to the one  above in the one-dimensional case.

Comment: This answers my question perfectly. However, I wonder what happens when $f$ is a polynomial. 

Comment: I think that when $f$ is a polynomial  your guess is correct, but I do not have a proof.

Comment: Dear Liviu, I'm not sure I understand the edit. The condition that $f(x)-ax$ be perfect for $a\gg 0$ does not imply that it is perfect for almost all $a$. Indeed, the function $\sin(x)+ax$ is perfect for $|a|>1$ (there are no critical points). Or am I missing something?

Comment: @ Mark: I guess you are right. Thanks for pointing this out.

Comment: @ Lior  I now have a proof that your guess is correct for any polynomial $f$. See the link below http://liviusmathblog.blogspot.com/2012/07/excellent-polynomial-mappings.html